# Compare 2 columns of 2 CSV files with Python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I'd like to compare 2 csv's.

The first: first.csv has D-column mail. I would like to compare this column of mails with the column D of the second.csv file. If a mail from first.csv is in the second.csv file, then delete the corresponding line containing the mail in second.csv.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Basically it extracts first file's d column as list and loops on second dataframe to filter and then overwrite the same file. It is using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

firstFileDF = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
secondFileDF = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

# firstFileDF
print(firstFileDF.to_string())

#          d
# 0  mail001
# 1  mail002
# 2  mail003

print(secondFileDF.to_string())
#          d
# 0  mail001
# 1  mail004

firstFileDFList = firstFileDF['d'].tolist()

for i in firstFileDFList:
    secondFileDF = secondFileDF[secondFileDF['d'] != i ]
print(secondFileDF.to_string())

#         d
# 1  mail004

# to write csv
secondFileDF.to_csv("file2.csv", sep='|')
```